# Creating Installer

Tags: c#, winforms

What I want to do is when the user installs my Application is to create a demo licence for them.   The demo licence will be valid for a limited amount of time.  My question is how can I do that in the installer project,  is it even possible to create dynamic files in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is not creating a license. It is more of a problem to make the application apply the intent of the license.

If you assume that your software is adequately secure on the client (from decompilation, for example) then you can use a service on a trusted server to generate the license and return this to the client for subsequent use.

If you can't do this, there is no way to prevent the user from replaying the installation process to generate additional valid licenses at will.

If you have a commercial application, it will almost certainly be cheaper to use a commercial license wrapper to manage the licensing.

Comment: I have really been trying to avoid the hole Licence creation server idea.  I'm wondering if its going to be to much work for a product i still haven't sold any licence for yet.   But i have put so much work in to the application that i at least want to try and prevent people from miss using it.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to go about that?

Comment: If there is no hardware lock device, and no license server, there is nothing to prevent the users from rerunning the installation over and over again. Unless you have some trusted key to lock onto, you cannot enforce any license. You could try to use time as a key and force users to be connected to the net where you can check the time - use telnet time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov daytime for a sample (not necessarily recommended, but list at http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) service. You can then at least expire licenses when they get stale. Expect users to try to spoof your time checks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great (and free) installer called Inno Setup (see http://www.jrsoftware.org)

This will enable you to create an installer.

There is a plugin called Inno Download plugin (http://mitrich.net23.net/?/inno-download-plugin.html)

An idea would be to use the download plugin to include "Demo" dlls or files which will expire?